# C error causing function constant return value

Tags: c

When I call `getinfo()` I get a constant value of 8 with a 1 digit value, 9 with a 2 digit value, 10 with a 3 digit value. and so on.  In the function, the value is printed as expected, however when attempting to read the value in the main method, the value is as mentioned above.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(){
    float radius = 0;
    float height = 0;
    float cylvolume = 0;
    float spherevolume = 0;

    displaymyinfo();

    radius = getinfo();
    printf("\n r = %f", radius);

    height = getinfo();
    printf("\n h = %f", height);



    cylvolume = compute_cylinder_volume(radius, height);
    spherevolume = compute_sphere_volume(radius);


    printf("h = %f", height);

    printf("\n A cylinder with radius %f and height %f = %f cubic inches", radius, height, cylvolume);
    printf("\n Volume of sphere with radius: %f is %f cubic inches", radius, spherevolume);

    _getch();
    return 0;

}
int displaymyinfo(){
    printf("*********************\n");
    printf("*Info was here  *\n");
    printf("*and here*\n");
    printf("*even here     *\n");
    printf("*********************\n");
    return 0;
}

float getinfo(){
    float y = 0;
    do{
        printf("\n Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%f", &y);
    } while (y <= 0);

    printf("%f", y);
    return (y);
}

float compute_cylinder_volume(float r,float h){
    float vol = 0.0;
    vol = 3.14 * r * r * h;
    return vol;
}
float compute_sphere_volume(float rad){
    float vol = 0.0;
    vol = 4.0 / 3.0 * 3.14 * rad * rad * rad;
    return vol;
}
```

Comment: Try declaring your functions before you call them, or define them before `main`. For example, before `main`, put `float getinfo();`. I suspect when you compiled, you may have seen some warnings you ignored?

Comment: BTW: Are you really sure you have a C compiler there? Because I'm detecting MS-isms there (`#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` `#include <conio.h>`), which make me guess you are using VC++ and thus probably not actually C.

Comment: regarding lines like: float radius = 0;  This is initializing a float, therefore, to avoid a bunch of conversions, the lines should be like: float radius = 0.0f;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
    radius = getinfo();
```

appears before the function `getinfo()` is defined. C, being the helpful language it is, will assume that you intend to define a function that returns an integer. The fact that you define it to return a float later will not deter it from this belief.

Add

```
float getinfo();
```

somewhere above `main()` (or move `main()` to the bottom).

Comment: Same thing with the other two functions that return a float.

Comment: Any decent compiler will warn on such implicit declarations though, at least if you ask politely `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -std=c11` should be some of the compiler-options.